# Marked throwing errors (Markdown) - Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, markdown, javascript-marked

So I've been trying to get some type of `markdown` plugin for converting the markdown syntax into html but I am having lots of trouble. I am using meteor, however, I am not sure if that's really an issue.

I've tried the following plugin called: `Marked` (https://github.com/chjj/marked)

And I get these errors with it

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Markdown is not defined Markdown.Editor.js?e08938e553cc97311ffd455d7241f8fc57c82b64:52
(anonymous function) Markdown.Editor.js?e08938e553cc97311ffd455d7241f8fc57c82b64:52
(anonymous function) Markdown.Editor.js?e08938e553cc97311ffd455d7241f8fc57c82b64:2120
(anonymous function) Markdown.Editor.js?e08938e553cc97311ffd455d7241f8fc57c82b64:2122
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Converter' of undefined Markdown.Sanitizer.js?95ec2c6ab6938e5f2fb3d6cc600e6f43c2c3f13a:8
(anonymous function) Markdown.Sanitizer.js?95ec2c6ab6938e5f2fb3d6cc600e6f43c2c3f13a:8
(anonymous function) Markdown.Sanitizer.js?95ec2c6ab6938e5f2fb3d6cc600e6f43c2c3f13a:111
(anonymous function) Markdown.Sanitizer.js?95ec2c6ab6938e5f2fb3d6cc600e6f43c2c3f13a:113
```

I've tried other plugins like `pagedown-bootstrap` and other versions of the same plugin and I get similar errors with them too.

Is there something specific I am missing?

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out? I am getting the 'Converter' error as well while trying to use pagedown-bootstrap. I am also getting the error on line ~3400

Comment: Did you find another solution to get a similar type of editor in meteor?

Comment: I ended up using showdown

Comment: @SeanCallahan, I've posted an answer which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when using Pagedown. I think my problem was that Markdown.Sanitizer.js was being loaded too early, so window.Markdown didn't exist yet for it.

I fixed it by moving everything from Markdown.Sanitizer.js into Markdown.Converter.js. The end result can be seen on [my Github](https://github.com/szego/pagedown/blob/master/Markdown.Converter.js) (search for "Markdown.getSanitizingConverter" to see the Sanitizer.js content down near the end).

Then I don't load Markdown.Sanitizer.js, only the above Markdown.Converter.js and the usual Markdown.Editor.js. This seems to have fixed it for me.

If anyone with some more knowledge would like to weigh in on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mention that you get the error when using Marked instead of Pagedown. I'm not sure why that would be, unless you happened to accidentally also include the Pagedown scripts on the page unnecessarily?